# Set vs abstract space: what's the difference?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

According to wikipedia, roughly:

- A space is a set with some attached structure (measure, order, etc).
- An abstract space is a set with no structure attached

What is then the difference between a set and an abstract space? Is it the same as the difference between a pipe (abstract space) and a picture of a pipe (set)?

Comment: This wikipedia comment is so vague and idiosyncratic as to be useless.

Comment: Could you help with a proper definition?

Comment: To the person who voted this down: why? What could I have done so that the question structure meets your standards? I find it an interesting question that I could not find the answer to.

Comment: What Wikipedia article is this according to?

Comment: Wikipedia is great...until it's not. When you find something this baffling, there should be a voice in your head saying "Maybe the folks who wrote this...don't know what they're talking about, or aren't very good explainers, because this makes no sense to me." (There should be another voice saying, "Or maybe it's *me*," and presumably that was the one that led you here...)

Comment: I did not downvote, but my comment has given you a clue. That wikipedia comment is not helpful. Generally speaking, the notion of a "space" is not mathematically defined. What you could do to improve your question is to perhaps first tell us about what actual examples of "spaces" you are familiar with from your own mathematical background (vector spaces? topological spaces? any others?), and then to carefully formulate a mathematical question regarding similarites, differences, generalizations.

Comment: @JohnHughes I went with the first option, but then thought it's the pipe thing described above and thought I'd validate that

Comment: @LeeMosher thanks for the tips. However, in this case, I was merely looking for a philosophical, rather than analytical, discussion.

Comment: @arjafi started here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(mathematics)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you've misinterpreted that [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(mathematics)) that you linked to in the comments. It does say that a "space" is a set with some added structure; but it does *not* say that an "abstract space" is a set with no structure attached. The first statement is a useful heuristic for thinking about commonalities among the various types of spaces that one encounters (vector spaces, metric spaces, topological spaces, Hilbert spaces, measure spaces, etc.). But the second statement is just false. An abstract space is, in particular, a space -- which means that it will always have some added structure in addition to being a set.

There is no rigorous general mathematical definition of either term, "space" or "abstract space." If you're having trouble wrapping your head around the concept of "abstract space," perhaps a useful way to think about it is this: Once you understand the definition of a *vector space*, then all the theorems about vector spaces tell you useful information about every concrete example you come across ($\mathbb R^n$, the space of all polynomials in one real variable, etc.). But if you want to prove something about all vector spaces, then your proof is going to have to apply to an arbitrary vector space, without knowing anything about how it is specifically constructed. Thus, you might say "Let $V$ be an abstract vector space," meaning that it is some set with added structure that we know satisfies the definition of a vector space, but we know absolutely nothing else about it.